# Can't get cp command to work via CGI-script

Tags: bash, apache, cgi, raspberry-pi3, cp

I'm running a web server on a Pi3B+, using Apache. This is for an in-house library project, and the machine runs on its own AdHoc network. It will never have network contact with the outside world, so I'm not worried about security. Through a cgi script, I need to trigger a cp command, but that command is getting ignored. Here's a very simple bash script that isn't working:

```
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo '<html>'
echo '<head><title>Blah blah blah</title></head>'
echo 'Script is running'
echo '<body>'
/bin/cp /home/pi/query.sh /home/pi/newfile.sh
echo '</body></html>’
```

Similarly, I can't mount an attached drive, echo text to a file, or do anything else that manipulates files or volumes. I know that cgi is enabled on the server side because the "script is running" line gets echoed back to the client browser. I understand opening things up this way is a big security hole, but again, security is not an issue in this case. What can I do to allow this kind of access?

Thanks!

Comment: By default, the script is executed as user `www-data`, does `www-data` have write permission to `/home/pi/`?

Comment: try appending `2>&1` to the cp command and you should see any error messages in your webpage

Comment: Thanks jhnc, being able to see the error messages was very helpful. It confirmed that Bosz was correct – it was a permissions issue.